# What is the technology called that charges the Laptop's battery to only 80% while showing 100% in the OS and how do I know that my Laptop has it?

Tags: laptop, battery

A friend of mine told be about this and that it is on the hardware side and depends on the Laptop and not on the OS.
I am only charging my Laptop to 80% and let it uncharge until 20% which would be a waste if my Laptop uses the above mentioned technology already.

Maybe someone actually knows already if my Laptop, UX392FA, uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASUS calls this "ASUS Battery Health Charging", and Toshiba calls it "Battery LifeCycle eco charge mode".

[image: ASUS Battery Health Charging utility]
[image: Toshiba eco Utility]

The [manuals for the ASUS ZenBook S13 UX392FA](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-S13-UX392FA/HelpDesk_Manual/) should indicate whether there is a similar utility already installed. If not, you can [download it from ASUS](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/ASUS_Battery_Health_Charging/ASUS_Battery_Health_Charging_Win10_64_VER100002.zip) and see if it works on your laptop.

There are also utilities such as [Battery Limiter](https://windowsreport.com/software/battery-limiter/) that appear to work on any laptop by alerting the user when battery charge has reached a chosen limit so the that *user* can unplug the charger... which would seem to be a nuisance, and the continual charge-discharge cycle might not actually increase battery life.

BTW, the Toshiba battery saver seems to be implemented both in firmware and in software, since when set to limit charge to 80% in Windows, on a dual-boot laptop, that setting is *still respected when running under Ubuntu*!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows for sure (all the laptops I know), it is the battery software that controls this. I have one laptop that I move around and charge to 100% . This is a newer machine and the battery is very good.

I let this machine drop to 20 - 30% and the charge it to 100%.

I have another one that stays put (Windows Insider machine) and I have the Battery software set to charge it to 80% and then drop to 75% and charge again. It is an older machine but the battery is still good.

Check your battery software for this function.